# Android add badge to list

Tags: android

I have a list,and I want to add badge to each item.I am using this library:https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger

And this is my code:

```
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView nameView;
    ImageView imageView;
    BadgeView badge;
}
public void placeRandomUsers(final String search) {
    randomAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<JsonObject>(this, 0) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.random_bars, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.nameView=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tweet);
                holder.badge = new BadgeView(getContext(), holder.nameView);
                holder.badge.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                holder.badge.setBadgeBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#A4C639"));
                holder.imageView=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            if (position >= getCount() - 3 && search.equals("") == true) {
                //loadRandomUsers("");
            }
            JsonObject user=getItem(position);
            String name=user.get("name").getAsString();
            String image_url="http://domain/photos/profile/thumb/"+user.get("photo").getAsString();

            holder.nameView.setText(name);


            Ion.with(holder.imageView)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.twitter)
            .load(image_url);
            holder.badge.setText("1");
            holder.badge.show();
            return convertView;
        }
    };

    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(randomAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            //Log.w("Pos","asd"+randomAdapter.getItem(position).get("name").getAsString());
            startChat(randomAdapter.getItem(position));

        }
    });
    loadRandomUsers(search);
}
```

And this is my random_bars.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:padding="4dp"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:src="@drawable/twitter"/>

    <LinearLayout
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                android:id="@+id/handle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tweet"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I add badge to each item,`nameView` is not showing.Here the output:

[image]

If I remove the badge codes.Output is:

[image]

Here you can see.Image is showing but name is not showing when I use the badge class.What can be cause this ?

Comment: Your BadgeView layout parameters may be broken. Use Hierarchy Viewer to check them or log those parameters.

Comment: I think if layout parameters be broken badge didn't show.I think there is a different problem.

Comment: Maybe the parameters make it take all space.
Check badge's `layout_width` value. You can try to set it to `wrap_content`.

Comment: Badge have no xml.There is a working example:https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger/blob/master/src/viewbadger/demo/DemoActivity.java line 290. Can you check ? It's working.

Comment: BadgeView extends TextView, check the code: `https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger/blob/master/src/com/readystatesoftware/viewbadger/BadgeView.java`. I suggest you debug the method `applyLayoutParams`. You can also use Android Hierarchy Viewer to check the layout structure after your add the Badge.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my random_bars.xml code to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:padding="4dp"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:src="@drawable/twitter"/>

    <LinearLayout
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
                android:id="@+id/handle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tweet"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Problem fixed.